# Cannot load module 'Snapkit' as 'Snapkit'

Tags: ios, xcode, snapkit

I've tried every way of installing 'Snapkit' but so far I'm not having much luck.

I'm using the following:-
Xcode 8.3.3

So far I've tried following all the documentation online to solve the issue, however it still isn't working. Including following the steps [here](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/xcode/quick-tip-fix-use-legacy-swift-issue-in-xcode-8-beta-3/).

The current error message is "Cannot load module 'Snapkit' as 'Snapkit".

Although previously the message was no such module 'Snapkit'.

Answer (score 2):

Typo in case - Snap**K**it, not Snapkit.

```
import SnapKit
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error recently. That's why I saw your question. I rebuilt and ran the app. After the build is finished it now recognizes SnapKit )). If you opened it through workspace and if the contents of the pod file are ok, then it should open. Try building the project and type SnapKit after it.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure if you're using Cocoapods as your dependency manager that you're loading the Xcode WorkSpace and not the project file. Otherwise try cleaning the project and rebuilding.